# pywin32com - Excel process closes for one script but not for the other

Tags: python, excel, process, win32com

I have two quite simple scripts:

1. Open the file, refresh the pivot, save and close. Excel closes completely at the end

```
import win32com.client
import pythoncom
import time
import os

pythoncom.CoInitialize()
xlapp = win32com.client.DispatchEx("Excel.Application")
xlapp.DisplayAlerts = True
xlapp.Visible = True
xlapp.AskToUpdateLinks = False
wb = xlapp.Workbooks.Open(path)

while True:
    try:        
        ws = wb.Worksheets['Sheet1']
        ws.Activate()
        ws.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("[dim_POS_reported_months]").CurrentPageName ="APR'22"
        xlapp.CalculateUntilAsyncQueriesDone()
        ws.PivotTables('PivotTable1').PivotCache().Refresh()
        xlapp.CalculateUntilAsyncQueriesDone()
        wb.Save()
        print("File saved...")
            
        wb.Close(True)
        wb = None
        del(wb)

        xlapp.Quit()
        del xlapp
        xlapp = None

        pythoncom.CoUninitialize()  

        break

    except Exception as ex: #catch exceptions

        traceback.print_exc()
```

2. Go through all the Excel files in the directory, make the same change in each file, save and close. In this one however the Excel doesn't close completely at the end. There's a background process Excel.EXE hanging forever

```
import win32com.client
import pythoncom
import time
import os

pythoncom.CoInitialize() 
path = "C:/Users/User/Desktop/Python"
suffix = "xlsx"
dirs = os.listdir(path)

while True:
    try:
    
        for file in dirs:

            if file.endswith(suffix):

               xlapp = win32com.client.DispatchEx("Excel.Application")
               xlapp.DisplayAlerts = True
               xlapp.Visible = True
               xlapp.AskToUpdateLinks = False
                    
               wb = xlapp.Workbooks.Open(os.path.join(path,file))
               ws = wb.Worksheets('Sheet1')
                    
               ws.Range("J7:J25").Copy()
               ws.Range("N7:N25").Select()
               ws.Paste()

               wb.Save()
               wb.Close(True)
               wb = None
               del(wb)
                    
               xlapp.Quit()
               del xlapp
               xlapp = None
               pythoncom.CoUninitialize()

        break

    except Exception as ex: 

        traceback.print_exc()
```

Why would Excel process not close at the end of the second script?

Comment: Is your first script as is?  The indentation seems wrong.

Comment: You don't need `CoInitialize()` and `CoUninitialize()` in this context as `win32com` does this for you automatically for the main thread (you still need the calls for other threads). Also, perhaps try `Dispatch()` rather than `DispatchEx()`. Also, why create a new Excel dispatch on each iteration of the loop ... just create one `xlApp` and re-use it, then close it at the end.

Comment: @ewong , sorry I messed up the indentation in the first script when copying, just fixed it in the original post

Comment: @DS_London in the first script if I take out `CoInitialize()` and `CoUninitialize()` the Excel also doesn't close completely that's why I thought it's crucial to use it in the second script as well

Comment: @DS_London I just tried 2nd script without `CoInitialize()` and `CoUninitialize()`, with `Dispatch()` instead of `DispatchEx()`, also tried one `xlApp` before the loop -  in all 3 cases result is always the same: Excel process hanging in the background at the end